# Move menu icon to right side on action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can i change the position of elements in default action bar of?

I want to move the menu icon to right side without use a component.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRcLL.png)

Comment: What do you want to happen when you press the menu icon on the right side?  Slide-out drawer from the right?

Comment: I suggest not to implement that design pattern, that is one of the most important aspects of the android design guidelines, considering that, the menu should be consistent across all applications. If you must do that, I would just add the menu icon as a drawable, and add it into your menu.xml file.

Comment: I want to do this beacuse is the layout of my client, and i can`t change this.

How is the schema to insert the icon with drawable? You know any website with a link with a tutorial?